# Duplicate SMS or network issue?

Tags: android, duplicates, sms, smsmanager

I have a messaging app which sends an SMS. Some of my clients said that the text messages are getting sent twice. I have custom logs (saved in sqlite) to log data about the messages (date, time, attempts, etc). In the logs I can see that the text messages are sent only a single time.

This is the method to send SMS:

```
private void send(String message, String phoneNumber, PendingIntent pendingIntentSent, PendingIntent pendingIntentDelivered) {
     SmsManager smsManager = getSMSManager();

     ArrayList<String> dividedText = smsManager.divideMessage(message);

     boolean isMultiPartText = false;

     if (dividedText.size() == 1) {
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pendingIntentSent, pendingIntentDelivered);
     }
     else {
         isMultiPartText = true;

         ArrayList<PendingIntent> piSentList = null;
         ArrayList<PendingIntent> piDeliveredList = null;

         if (pendingIntentSent != null) {
             piSentList = new ArrayList<>();
         }

         if (pendingIntentDelivered != null) {
             piDeliveredList = new ArrayList<>();
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < dividedText.size(); i++) {
             if (pendingIntentSent != null)
                 piSentList.add(pendingIntentSent);

             if (pendingIntentDelivered != null)
                 piDeliveredList.add(pendingIntentDelivered);
         }

         smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, dividedText, piSentList, piDeliveredList);
     }

     DBLogger.getDefault()
             .log("PI sent: ").log(pendingIntentSent != null ? "NOT NULL" : null).log(NEW_LINE)
             .log("PI delivered: ").log(pendingIntentDelivered != null ? "NOT NULL" : null).log(NEW_LINE)
             .log("Message size: ").log(message.length()).log(", parts: ").log(dividedText.size()).log(NEW_LINE)
             .log("Multipart: ").log(isMultiPartText)
             .flush();
 }

 private SmsManager getSMSManager() {
     SmsManager smsManager = null;

     try {
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
             int smsId = SmsManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId();
             smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(smsId);
         }
         else {
             smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     if (smsManager == null)
         smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

     return smsManager;
 }
```

The devices are:

1. Samsung s6 (SAMSUNG-SM-G890A)
2. Samsung s8+ (SM-G955U)

And their SIM Info:

```
Text delivery reports = not enabled
Carrier=AT&T - US
Roaming=false

mcc=310
mnc=410
```

People sent me screenshots with their messaging app and I can see the duplicated messages, but in my logs I can see only 1 entry.

I think that AT&T or the Device is wrong here. I have read on support forums that if the device doesn't have a good signal, sometimes the text messages are sent twice.

Comment: check where are you call `send(....)`

Comment: I'm sure you have diagnosed the issue thoroughly, but I had a similar issue when sending messages using Firebase. I discovered that my `onClick` method was firing twice because I did not disable the "send button". Occasionally my "send button" was getting tapped twice rapidly without the user realizing they had--My fault. So now I disable the button until the send method returns a response.

Comment: That was my first thought that the method is called twice, but If it was, why I can't see duplicate logs? (This was the reasons why I'm logging the message's data).